# Keywords object is empty when making authenticated YouTube API call with Java YouTubeService class

Tags: java, youtube-api

I am trying to fetch videos from MY OWN YouTube account, so that I get the keywords/tags for each video. I'm trying to use the most simple approach for making an authenticated call to get my videos with keywords/tags.

Here is my Java code:

```
String clientID = "XXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com";
String devKey = "MY-DEVELOPER-KEY";
String userEmail = "MY-GMAIL-EMAIL";
String userPassword = "MY-GMAIL-PASSWORD";
String authorName = "MY-YOUTUBE-ACCOUNT-NAME";
String url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos";

YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService( clientID, devKey );
service.setUserCredentials( userEmail, userPassword );

YouTubeQuery query = new YouTubeQuery( new URL( url ) );
query.setAuthor( authorName );

VideoFeed videoFeed = service.query( query, VideoFeed.class );
```

Please, help me understand what I am doing wrong, to authenticate and get those media keywords.

If you are going to refer me to another authentication option, please, show an example of using that other option for my specific scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into the behavior described in [this blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/03/keeping-things-fresh.html): your API calls are going against the search index, and those results will never have the keywords in them.

There's [an example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java#Retrieving_Uploads) that shows how you could request the uploads feed in Java using v2 of the Data API; you can modify that example to use the channel name `default` instead of `username` and you'll automatically pull in the uploads feed for the currently authenticated account.

Comment: Thank you for your response Jeff. It has worked for me. However, I have a couple of follow up questions:

Comment: 1) Is it possible to authenticate for my scenario using ClientID/Secret/DevKey instead of login/password?

2) Is it possible to retrieve the feed in JSON (similar what we get when we call API with parameters: v=2&alt=jsonc), so that I can return it to my JavaScript code that knows how to parse jsonc structure.
         
Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's not possible to use the Java GData client library and get it to return JSON-C. If you need to get back JSON-C data, you should probably make raw HTTP requests with the `alt=jsonc&v=2` URL parameter set, and the proper Authentication header set as well. It's possible to use a mechanism other than ClientLogin with the Java GData client library, but I don't have any code samples handy.

Comment: Jeff, where can I find an example of how to construct a proper authentication header that would fit my scenario?

Comment: If you're using ClientLogin, there's an example here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_clientlogin

Answer (score 0):

Here is what finally worked for me to get JSON-C feed with tags (keywords):

```
    /** AUTHENITICATION **/

    // HTTP connection        
    URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    // Form the POST parameters
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    content.append("Email=").append(URLEncoder.encode("MY-GMAIL-LOGIN", "UTF-8"));
    content.append("&Passwd=").append(URLEncoder.encode("MY-GMAIL-PASSWORD", "UTF-8"));
    content.append("&service=").append(URLEncoder.encode("youtube", "UTF-8"));
    OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(content.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
    outputStream.close();

    // Check response status
    int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
    if( responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK ) {
        // EXCEPTION
    }

    // Get the token from the response
    String token;
    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = null;
    while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        if ( line.indexOf("Auth=") > -1 ) {
            token = line.split("=")[1];
        }
    }

    /** JSON-C FEED WITH TAGS **/

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    GetMethod method = new GetMethod("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=50&start-index=1");

    // set the authentication headers
    method.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=" + token);
    method.setRequestHeader("X-GData-Key", "key=MY-DEV-KEY"); 
    method.setRequestHeader("GData-Version", "2");
    method.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    // Make the call
    int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
    if ( statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK ) {
        // EXCEPTION
    }
    String JSON = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
```